# Issues reseting root password in mysql 8 on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, authentication, root

I am using MySQL 8 on Windows 10, and I am trying to reset my root password. (Shared lab computers, no idea what the original password was). I am following these directions:

https://www.cnblogs.com/jackmary/p/9746454.html

and

https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1545701135-How-to-reset-root-password-in-MySQL-8

Once I get to the step of running:

```
mysql -u root
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

I get the error

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000) at line 1: The MySQL server is running with the 
--skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I have also tried running

```
mysqld --init-file=/mysql-init.txt --console
```

but I get the access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'.
What should I try next to reset this password?

Comment: Which option did you choose 1 or 2 . from the second link, the first is in Chinese....

Comment: Follow the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: @nbk I started with 2, but ended up at one after translating it to english.

Comment: @danblack the official docs are the same steps as option 2. I will try to run through it again, but I think it will end up with the same errors.

Comment: Both ways work, with the first command you put mysql into a state that he accepts manipulation. that's why you can log in withput password. The first option makes the same, but you give it the command right inb biit up, so that it will run without prompting for a password. Check also the erro log if something is a miss

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
After running through it one more time, and using --console, I got an error about a missing data directory. I thought it was just the data file, but it turns out the latest version of the mysql installer puts the my.ini in a different place than what mysql expects. Running through the steps outlined here:

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,673459,673506#msg-673506

Then through the steps in option 2 fixed it for me!

Comment: Glad that worked. Sadly no-one has put in a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com) so it hasn't been fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I think I might file a bug report, thanks for the link!